# Update Dataframe Schema Read Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, schema

I am trying to read in a schema from hdfs to load into my dataframe. This allows the schema to be updated and reside outside the Spark Scala code. I was wondering what the best way was to do this? Below is what I have currently inside the code.

```
val schema_example = StructType(Array(
    StructField("EXAMPLE_1", StringType, true),
    StructField("EXAMPLE_2", StringType, true),
    StructField("EXAMPLE_3", StringType, true))

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 
   val df_example = get_df("example.txt", schema_example)
}

def get_df(filename: String, schema: StructType): DataFrame = {
    val df = sqlContext.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("delimiter","~")
      .schema(schema)
      .option("quote", "'")
      .option("quoteMode", "ALL")
      .load(filename)
    df.select(df.columns.map(c => trim(col(c)).alias(c)): _*)
  }
```

Comment: have you considered using parquet dataformat which has both the schema and the data in file and supports excellent compression and optimizations?

Answer (score 0):

Better would be to read Schema from HOCON Config file, which can be updated as and when required.

```
schema[
  {
     columnName = EXAMPLE_1
     type = string
  },
  {
     columnName = EXAMPLE_2
     type = string
  },
  {
     columnName = EXAMPLE_3
     type = string
  }
]
```

They you can read this file using `ConfigFactory`.
This will be more better and cleaner way to maintain file schema.